# Query/Relationship from multiple Fields to a single Field in Related Table/Query

Tags: ms-access

Apologies if this is answered in SO. I searched and couldn't find an obvious duplicate. I am new to Access and inherited an old Access MDB (2000 File Format). [Note: I am using Office 365.]

Data is in 5 tables. However, only 4 are connected with Relationships. The fifth (unconnected) Table is a mashup of different data in 3 fields: `Type`, `Code`, and `Description`. `Type` has multiple rows with repeated values. Each Type row has a unique `Code` and `Description`. Each unique Type corresponds to a column in Table_1, and the Codes are values found in that column. (There are 3000 rows in Table_5 with over 250 unique Types, each with 1-500+ Codes.)
Here is a simplified version of Table_5:

```
Type   Code  Description
Atype  A     Atype_A_Description
Atype  B     Atype_B_Description
Atype  X1    Atype_X1_Description
...
Class  1     Class_1_Description
Class  2     Class_2_Description
Class  9     Class_9_Description
...
Source A     Source_A_Description
Source A1    Source_A1_Description
Source A2    Source_A2_Description
...
```

To complicate things, there isn't an exact match between the Field names in Table_1 and the Type entries in Table_5. (For example the `Atype` values in Table_5 correspond to a Field named `ACC_TYPE1` in Table_1.)

I'm working on a method to get the Description from Table_5 based on a Field Name and Value from Table_1. I did this for 1 (hardcoded) Type. I created a Query for that Type in Table_5, and connected it to Table_1 with a Relationship.

Here's what I did:
**Table_5_Atype_Query** (as SQL, let me know if another format is preferred in SO)

```
SELECT Table_5.[Type], Table_5.[Code], Table_5.[Description]
FROM Table_5
WHERE (((Table_5.[Type])="Atype"));
```

The **Relationship** is:

```
Table/Query:  Related Table/Query:
Table_1       Table_5_Atype_Query
ACC_TYPE1     Code
```

This works perfectly to get the Description field referencing Code from Table_5 based on values of ACC_TYPE1 in Table_1. It is NOT scalable to lookup Descriptions for other Type/Code pairs. (I would need 250 unique queries and relationships.) Put another way, I'd like to create a method to get the Description from Table_5 based on any Column Name and Value from Table_1. Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: A UNION query can rearrange multiple fields to a single field but there is a limit of 50 SELECT lines in a UNION. You have 250+ fields to rearrange. I expect VBA and temp tables will be needed to rearrange this data to a relatable structure.

Comment: I'm not surprised I need more Tables for all 250+ fields. I don't need all of them. Over 100 Fields only have 1 or 2 Codes. For starters, I'm interested in a few Fields (<5). Suppose I want to connect [Table_1].Field1name -> [Table_5].Type=='value1'; [Table_1].Field2name -> [Table_5].Type=='value2'; [Table_1].Field3name -> [Table_5].Type=='value3'; then return Description based on matching Code. (In general, Fieldiname and valuei are not the same.) Do I need another table to map [Table_1].Fieldinames to [Table_5].Type values?

Answer (score 0):

A UNION query can rearrange fields to a normalized data structure.

UNION query with 5 fields:

```
SELECT ID, field1 as Code, "f1" as src from table1
UNION SELECT ID, field2, "f2" from table1
UNION SELECT ID, field3, "f3" from table1
UNION SELECT ID, field4, "f4" from table1
UNION SELECT ID, field5, "f5" from table1;
```

Of course, use your actual field and table names.
Now use that query in another query joining to table5.

There is a limit of 50 SELECT lines. There is no query designer or wizard for UNION - must use SQLView.